# Signal is not activating process?

Tags: process, signals, vhdl, fpga, timing

so I seem to be having a problem in regards to flag signal getting asserted. So basically I am implementing i2c interface between 2 fpga's. My master will send over 50 bytes. On my slave side I want to store the byte coming in into an array. So I check when ever the whole byte is read and available i put it into an array. Now the problem is that after i fill up the whole array i want to assert a signal that should activate a process. My problem is that when the signal is asserted and the process is activated that that I am stuck in the idle loop forever, which confuses me because I was under the assumption that when i enter the process and check the flag signal assertion condition that it is suppose to be high. So is the problem that my signal is not activating the process or is my problem that the by the time i check the flag assertion conditional that the flag already went back to 0?
I have attached some code:

```
  signal i : integer range 0 to 49 := 0;

  type field_array is array(0 to 49) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
process(clk,rst) 
begin

if( rst = '1') then

    i <= 0;

elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then

    if(data_available = '1') then

        array_of_data(i) <= Master_Data;

        i <= i + 1;

    end if;

    if(i = 49) then

        i <= 0; -- reset index back to zero

    end if;

end if;

end process;

flag <= '1' when i = 49 else '0'; 

process(state,flag)
begin

next_state   <= state;

case (state) is 

    when idle =>

        if(flag = '1') then

            next_state <= Send_data;

        end if;

     when Send_data =>...
```

Comment: its not clear from your code snippet how `next_state` (set when your flag changed) is supposed to change your `state` signal to trigger the next state of your state machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bounds check failure on your assignment, `i <= i+1;`. It is trying to evaluate it before the check that is performed later (`if i=49...`).

Change the synchronous part of you code to:

```
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    if data_available = '1' then
        array_of_data(i) <= Master_Data;
        if i = 49 then
            i <= 0;
        else
            i <= i + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end if;
```

EDIT:

You can see that the flag is being asserted and the state changes [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsC7u.png).

Further EDIT:

Consider making your state machine synchronous and removing the `next_state` signal. eg.

```
type state_t is (idle_s, send_s, others_s);
signal state : state_t := idle_s;
...
process(clk,rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        -- rst
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        case (state) is
            when idle_s =>
                if flag = '1' then
                    state <= send_s;
                else
                    state <= idle_s;
                end if;
            when send_s =>
            -- Do stuff
            when others =>
            -- stuff
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

If you want to assign your outputs as soon as your state changes, you can use a two process state machine. One of the processes (synchronous) is used to control state transitions, the other is used to control the output (combinational). You would effectively have another process similar to the first:

```
process(state)
begin
    case state is
        when idle_s =>
            my_output <= '0';
        when send_s =>
            -- Assign output as necessary
            my_output <= '1';
        when others =>
        --assign output
    end case;
end process;
```

An example is shown [here](http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_state_machines.htm).

Comment: Thank you for that correction. Yes it seems to be working fine on simulation but when I run it on my fpga it seems to only be sticking on the idle state(using led's to check states) . Correct me if I am wrong but when flag is asserted (0 -> 1),the process should activate and when i check the  to see if (flag = '1') the condition should be true right?

Comment: Correct. After a further look, I would probably modify your state controller process as well; make it synchronous, and get rid of the `next_state` signal

Comment: I get a bounds check error on that line from GHDL when I try to simulate it

Comment: @gsm apologies. I'm wrong. You would get a bounds check failure on your assignment.

Comment: Thanks @gsm for the modify recommendation and help. For some reason it now works when i use the combinational process that i first posted. Strange. Anywho, The synchronous process you mentioned works great, thank you but the reason I did not start out going for synchronous in the first place was because inside my send data case i plan on asserting some outputs and I want them to be asserted as soon as that case is hit reacting on the same clock cycle, while on the other hand if i were to go synchronous I believe the outputs i would assert would change one clock cycle later.

Comment: You can use a two process state machine to achieve what you are after. Use a sync process to control your state transitions and a combinatoinal process to assign your outputs. I've updated my answer and provided an example link

Comment: Thank you, I will go ahead and try that method.